# remove the file but still located

Tags: filesystem

Ive save the file wejnswpwhitespacefix.php in /var/www/trytry/

I deleted the file wejnswpwhitespacefix.php

```
root@mai:/var/www/trytry$ rm wejnswpwhitespacefix.php
```

the when I type locate wejnswpwhitespacefix.php

```
 root@mai:/var/www/trytry$ locate wejnswpwhitespacefix.php
```

I still locate it:

```
 /var/www/trytry/wejnswpwhitespacefix.php
```

the I try to remove the file again:

```
root@mai:/var/www/trytry$ rm wejnswpwhitespacefix.php
rm: cannot remove `wejnswpwhitespacefix.php': No such file or directory
```

Please Help

Comment: Do the Command updatedb & , then Try to locate it Won't be there..

Answer (score 1):

The `locate` command consults a database rather than scanning the filesystem, as scanning the whole filesystem can be quite time consuming.  As a result, the database can become out of sync with the filesystem for a time after you add or remove files.  The database is updated when the `updatedb` command is run, which is usually scheduled to be done once a day.  Hence, it is normal for `locate` to still show files immediately after you have removed them.

Answer (score 0):

Do the Command `updatedb &` , then Try to locate it Won't be there..
The Database have not updated So what it shows that file was there, Once the updatedb Done It will Not Show in locate ..